# Using Ubuntu 18.04 with Budgie environment, dock vanished

Tags: settings, dock, budgie

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with a Budgie desktop environment. I was in the middle of doing final touch-ups when my dock vanished. (I had been using it not two minutes earlier.) I double checked that it was installed (it was) and it was positioned at the left of my screen. I looked through the gnome tweak tool and discovered that my extensions tab was also gone. Again, I made sure it was installed (it was).

I also downloaded Dash to Dock to see if that would work. Again, the dock would not come up. I can only open the settings from the terminal (the program doesn't show up anywhere else), and the settings show that it's at the bottom of the screen, but it isn't showing up.

It also appears my terminal command has changed, but into what I do not know. I have tried Google for every issue I've mentioned and have no answers.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

(I've attached pictures of my tweak tool and settings.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNRcY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5atT.png

Comment: Potentially `budgie-panel --replace` could work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have uninstalled some packages possibly due to uninstalling packages that these depend upon.

Suggestion here is to reinstall these packages.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-budgie-desktop budgie-desktop-environment plank
```

Logout and login.

The standard side dock is called plank. If it doesn't autostart then open budgie-settings and add an autostart for plank.

Comment: I realized that that's exactly what happened - I didn't know what Plank even was, so when I read the description in the software downloader (something like "Stupidly simple"), I thought I was safe to uninstall it.